# asp.net mvc add parameter with each action view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a site which have many action like article, blog, news, stories, myths, books, audio, video.
Now I want if i pass a query string in index action like 
wwww.mysite.com/english 
then every action must be have this parameter automatically like
wwww.mysite.com/article/english
wwww.mysite.com/blog/english
wwww.mysite.com/news/english
wwww.mysite.com/stories/english
wwww.mysite.com/myths/english
wwww.mysite.com/books/english
wwww.mysite.com/audio/english
wwww.mysite.com/video/english

Please help me and suggest a good way

Comment: Will you always pass in a language? What does the system do if you don't pass in a language?

Comment: I have website in which two paramenters are passed for each action 1. hindi 2. english if no one pass then default is hindi. I have two column in database Harticle and Earticle if hindi is pass then Harticle column will be used otherwise Earticle column will be used. by this method single view will be used for both otherwise I have to create two view one for Hindi and second for English. If I get above method what is asked, it will be good for me

Answer (score 0):

Store the passed passed parameter in a session variable and then access on each action. Example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string lang)
{
Session["Language"]= lang;
return View();
}
```

And then fetch in other actions like:

```
public ActionResult News()
{
string lang= Session["Language"].ToString();
// Do something with the lang...
return View();
}
```